# Model selection based on "generalization set"

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, model-selection, generalization

I'm working on a very general problem in machine learning where I have to choose from different models or from updates which would lead to different models. A first idea was to define a "generalization set" disjoint from the training, test and possible development set and choose the best model on the "generalization set". It has some resemblance with meta-learning or population-based optimization methods but has its own overfitting problems. Does someone know about research involving such a "generalization set" or similar approaches?

Comment: How is this different from the standard train-test split setup?

Comment: In the standard setting, you would use the complete training set to calculate the updates. Here, you would calculate the updates on only a part of it and would use the other part to choose the best update. This only makes sense if you have multiple updates to choose from. 

The bigger question is really how to choose between different updates.